How to manage properly Thread when using Spring Boot AsyncRabbitTemplate?
I am fetching batches of 10 records from database in a do while loop until the last batch contains less than 10 records.
do {
    List<CompletableFuture<Boolean>> operations = records.stream().map(this::publishMessage).toList();
    CompletableFuture.allOf(operations.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();
} while (records.size() < 10)

For each record, publish a message asynchronously and wait for them all to be confirmed and the record to be deleted.
CompletableFuture<Boolean> publishMessage(Record record) {
    return asyncRabbitTemplate
                .convertSendAndReceive(this.eventsProperties.getQueueName(), event)
                .getConfirm()
                .thenApply(
                    published -> {
                        if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(published)) {
                            log.warn("Failed to publish Outbox Message to MQ");
                            return false;
                        }
                        deleteRecord(record);
                        return published;
                    });
}

When I am testing this code with more than 1350 records, I get an OutOfMemoryError Exception.
How can I control this to make sure each thread has freed it's resource before starting the next batch?
I tried changing some spring.rabbitmq.* properties but I didn't found anything helpful.
